# Shiny - Downloading DT table without downloading action buttons

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am having trouble with the download/copy/print etc buttons in Shiny and can't get any of the suggested fixes to work.
I have a DT table in Shiny with buttons to download as CSV etc. It is a two-column table.

There is also a third column with a 'clipboard' button that allows the user to copy the selected row.
I am trying to exclude this third column when downloading/printing etc. Please see below the DT:

[image: DT]

The code I have to exclude specific columns from export works in general, but doesn't exclude the third column with the action button. The code to only include columns 1 & 2 in the export is in Section 3 & Highlighted below:

[image: below]

Sections 1,2 & 4 have codes pertaining to the "clipboard action button".

I've searched a ton online and looked through the different reference docs but can't seem to find a way to exclude column 3 when exporting.

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
buttons = list(
  list(extend = "copy", exportOptions = list(columns = c(0,1)), 
  list(extend = "excel", exportOptions = list(columns = c(0,1)),
  ......
)
```